# How would you add to a value using an html button?

Tags: javascript, console, counting

So, I'm writing a code for a website, making a game, pretty much. I've been experimenting with code, trying to make a button add an integer (1) to the value "anger" of the site. I also want the value of anger to be sent to the console every time it's updated. So far, I haven't been able to get anything in the console. It's just an idea I'm trying to see to the end. Here's the code:

```js
var anger = 0;

var incrementAndSet = function () {
  anger = anger + 1;
  document.getElementById("btn").console.log ("Anger level:" + anger);
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = incrementAndSet;

incrementAndSet();
console.log(anger)
```

```html
    <h1>Anger Minigame</h1>

    <p>
      This site is a game, meant for you to press the below button, 
      making the site angrier and angrier. 
    
      <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    </p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("anger").console.log` whats' this?

Comment: i'm pulling from a button with the class id anger. let me edit this really quick, ill add the html portion as well.

Comment: Please provide you HTML code also or recreate the issue using https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Camashima The point was that it makes no sense; `console` isn't a property of an HTML element, and `console.log` logs to the console. If you want to set the text or HTML value of an element then do that.

Comment: @KeshavBajaj No reason to use JSFiddle for a wee snippet.

Comment: I'm trying to send the new value of "anger" to the console.

Comment: @Camashima Then why are you getting an HTML element? You correctly log `anger` at the bottom of the JS. Are you trying to attach an event handler to the button?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make the button add 1 to anger, then log that NEW value. I don't get any errors on my end, but I don't get any responses either.

Comment: @Camashima You most certainly get an error, because there's an error.

Comment: @Camashima I have removed all but the actual important parts, although that doesn't change the error.

Comment: I don't get any though. I'm using glitch to run the site, and I don't get errors for some reason.

Comment: @Camashima Look in the JS console. If there are no errors there, and no errors anywhere else, it's not a useful tool for experimenting with. There's also zero reason this can't be run locally or in JSFiddle/etc. where you *can* see errors.

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't typically use JSFiddle, it's usually just because I don't have access to it, due to campus wifi restrictions, but whenever I'm home, I forget I CAN go on it. Also, I'm on a chromebook without any sort of local terminal.

Comment: @Camashima https://chromeos.dev/en/web-environment etc. Developing simple HTML/JS webapps on Chromebooks is reasonably straight-forward. Although... if there are restrictions like that on your school WiFi I'd have concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element with id 'anger' in your code.
Also there is an error in js which is fixed below.

```js
var anger = 0;

// Define a function,
// which you can reuse for the task (inc & set in the DOM)
var incrementAndSet = function() {
  anger = anger + 1;
  document.getElementById("anger").innerHTML = "Anger level:" + anger
  console.log("Anger level:" + anger);
}
// increment and set on click
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = incrementAndSet;

// initialize
incrementAndSet();
```

```html
<div id='anger'>
0
</div>
<div id='btn'>Button</div>
```

Comment: I originally did have a DOM, but I couldn't call it with anything.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix in your code.

I have added a new div which will show the current level of anger

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Hello world!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- this is the start of content -->
    <h1>Anger Minigame</h1>
    <p>
      This site is a game, meant for you to press the below button, making the
      site angrier and angrier.

      <div id="count">0</div>
      <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    </p>

    <script>
      var anger = 0;

      // Define a function,
      // which you can reuse for the task (inc & set in the DOM)
      var incrementAndSet = function () {
        anger = anger + 1;
        document.getElementById("count").textContent = anger
        console.log("Anger Level: " + anger)
      };

      // increment and set on click
      document.getElementById("btn").onclick = incrementAndSet;

      console.log(anger);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes-

1. id anger is not defined in your Dom.
2. mistake inside js file

**try out the code below I have fixed the issue**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  

  var anger = 0;

    // Define a function,
    // which you can reuse for the task (inc & set in the DOM)
    var incrementAndSet = function () {
      anger = anger + 1;
      document.getElementById("anger").innerHTML=anger;
      console.log(anger);
    }
    // increment and set on click
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = incrementAndSet;

    // initialize
    incrementAndSet();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Hello world!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- this is the start of content -->
    <h1>
      Anger Minigame
    
    </h1>
    <p>
      This site is a game, meant for you to press the below button, 
      making the site angrier and angrier. </p>

      <p id="anger"></p>
    
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
      
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Camashima I hope this helped you ! but if you still have doubts you can share!

Answer (score 0):

Also there is an error in js which is fixed below.

```js
var anger = 0;


      var incrementAndSet = function () {
        anger = anger + 1;
        document.getElementById("anger").innerHTML = "Anger level:" + anger;
      };

      document.getElementById("btn").onclick = incrementAndSet


      incrementAndSet();
      console.log(anger);
```

```html
<div id="anger">  </div>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
```